# How to change value with count data

Tags: json, highcharts

I have json data with value but instead of display the value i want to display the count of value which is not in my json data. How to make var like select count(*) from ecgvalue?.
This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var processed_json = new Array();
            $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/query', function (data) {
                // Populate series
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    processed_json.push([data[i].id_data, data[i].ecgvalue]);
                }

                // draw chart
                $('#container2').highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        type: "column"
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: "ECG Graph"
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        type: 'category',
                        allowDecimals: false,
                        title: {
                            text: "Id Data"
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: "Value"
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                            name: 'ECG value',
                            data: processed_json
                        }]
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and this is my json

```
[{"id_data":1,"ecgvalue":3.3871},{"id_data":2,"ecgvalue":1.56892},{"id_data":3,"ecgvalue":1.60802},{"id_data":4,"ecgvalue":2.09677},{"id_data":5,"ecgvalue":1.99902},{"id_data":6,"ecgvalue":1.97947}]
```

I want to change value of y axis to count from ecgvalue, is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by `count from ecgvalue`. Do you want cumulated ecgvalues?

Comment: So you would like to get something like this chart? http://jsfiddle.net/0xzobrae/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by `count` you mean how many items are in the `processed_json` array (as you can with the SQL statement `count(*)`), then all you need is simply `processed_json.length`.

Here's a working example using the data you provided: https://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/t8pv7csn/

You can then use the `processed_json.length` however you wish in your code and/or chart options.

Comment: thats is what i've been looking for. One more, processed_jsin.length is count my data row?
can it works somehow to count each collumn i mean object?

Comment: @samydoyle `Array.length` is the number of items in `Array`. So, for `var myArray = [a,b,c,d]`, the value of `myArray.length` would be `4`. Also, for an object such as `var myObject = [{"key": "a", "value": 1},{"key": "b", "value": 2}]`, the value of `myObject.length` would be `2`. Is this what you wanted to know?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var processed_json = new Array();
            $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/query', function (data) {
                // Populate series
                var ecgCount = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
ecgCount  += data[i].ecgvalue
                    processed_json.push([data[i].id_data, data[i].ecgvalue]);
                }

                // draw chart
                $('#container2').highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        type: "column"
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: "ECG Graph"
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        type: 'category',
                        allowDecimals: false,
                        title: {
                            text: "Id Data"
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: ecgCount
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                            name: 'ECG value',
                            data: processed_json
                        }]
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Is this What you required.

Comment: Shudn't it be `processed_json.push([data[i].id_data, ecgCount]);` I think he wants the cumulated y axis.